# Sinatra I18n Fallbacks using Rack::Locale

Tags: ruby, internationalization, sinatra, i18n-gem

I'm trying to set up a simple Sinatra app with I18n, following [the recommended Sinatra recipe](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/development/i18n), and using `Rack:Locale` to determine the language.

My app.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'rack/contrib'
require 'i18n'
require 'i18n/backend/fallbacks'
require 'tilt/haml'

use Rack::Locale

configure do
  I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)
  I18n.load_path = Dir[File.join(settings.root, 'locales', '*.yml')]
  I18n.backend.load_translations
end

helpers do
  def t(*args)
    I18n.t(*args)
  end
end

get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

My locales/en.yml:

```
en:
  welcome: "Welcome!"
```

When I run `rackup` and visit the root path of my Sinatra app, I get the following:

```
I18n::InvalidLocale at /
"en-US" is not a valid locale
file: i18n.rb location: enforce_available_locales! line: 284
```

I thought that the `I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)` would handle this, by not finding `en-US` and falling back to `en` (which I have), but apparently not. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
```